# How to handle old data with database migrations?

Tags: database, database-design, database-migration

I'm jumping into a project that's been running for some time. One of my first tasks is to add a few columns that will essentially replace an existing column. What should I do with the old data?

The new columns are meant to "decompose" an existing column, as a way to add more granular details to the value. The following structure is conceptually the same as what I'm dealing with:

```
# Current Schema
TotalPrice: BigInt

# New Schema
BasePrice: BigInt
Markup: BigInt
Tax: BigInt
```

Conceptually speaking, `TotalPrice == (BasePrice + Markup + Tax)`.

As part of this migration, what's the best way to deal with all the rows that already have values for `TotalPrice`? I've worked out two options, and I'm looking for some authoritative guidance for which approach is "better" in terms of maintenance, reasoning, etc. I'm open to alternative approaches too.

### Keep `TotalPrice`

Hold onto the old data as-is, make the column read-only via the ORM (I'm using Django), and introduce conditionals in the code to check for a value in this "legacy" column first. This feels more complicated on the code level, but preserves the data in its originally intended mental model, making it easier to reason about and work with in the future.

### Moving `TotalPrice` into one of the new columns

Hold onto the data, but re-label it, so to speak. This would make the code cleaner, but set us up for potentially weird situations where only one of the new columns would have a value for a lot of records, while the expected situation is that all 3 of the new columns will have a value > 0.

To me, it seems like the first approach is better for the long term. It's more explicit (records with `TotalPrice` represent the information when it was created), and requires less commenting to explain "what's going on here", when dealing with columns that have an implied second meaning (e.g. `BasePrice` is both the base price but sometimes the `TotalPrice` for old records). But I'm not totally sure if holding onto this column and the associated code flows are worth an easier mental model.

Imagine a lot of code that looks like:

```py
if obj.total_price:
    return obj.total_price
else:
    return obj.base_price + obj.markup + obj.tax
```

Where we'll always have to do a form of duck-typing, to see if it's a "legacy" record.

"It doesn't really matter" is also an acceptable answer!

Comment: The end result should be a database with consistent valid data. If not then you will run into problems for example when someone wants average markup% over time - it wont work or will give invalid results for the old data. Is there any way to approximate or derive the other values? Even if its a best guess its probably better; if you are worried include an Estimated flag so you can make it clear.

Comment: Ah, that’s a great point: using the data consistently for comparisons over time is a wrinkle that I hadn’t considered! With this in mind, the second approach seems better, with an “estimate” flag being the real clincher for me. Thanks!